# Problems using Default navbar components from flowbite-react

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, flowbite

I have installed the requirements indecated [here](https://flowbite.com/docs/getting-started/react/).

After that copied the entired [Default navbar](https://flowbite-react.com/navbars) code in App.jsx file, the problem raised is

```
`Uncaught ReferenceError: React is not defined`.
`$$typeof: Symbol(react.forward_ref)`
```

- what is `react.forward_ref`?. Internet only shows something like `React.forwardRef.`
- How can resolve the problem?

**Default navbar** code

```
<Navbar
  fluid={true}
  rounded={true}
>
  <Navbar.Brand
    as={{
      $$typeof: Symbol(react.forward_ref),
      render: LinkWithRef
    }}
    to="/navbars"
  >
    <img
      src="https://flowbite.com/docs/images/logo.svg"
      className="mr-3 h-6 sm:h-9"
      alt="Flowbite Logo"
    />
    <span className="self-center whitespace-nowrap text-xl font-semibold dark:text-white">
      Flowbite
    </span>
  </Navbar.Brand>
  <Navbar.Toggle />
  <Navbar.Collapse>
    <Navbar.Link
      href="/navbars"
      active={true}
    >
      Home
    </Navbar.Link>
    <Navbar.Link
      as={{
        $$typeof: Symbol(react.forward_ref),
        render: LinkWithRef
      }}
      to="/navbars"
    >
      About
    </Navbar.Link>
    <Navbar.Link href="/navbars">
      Services
    </Navbar.Link>
    <Navbar.Link href="/navbars">
      Pricing
    </Navbar.Link>
    <Navbar.Link href="/navbars">
      Contact
    </Navbar.Link>
  </Navbar.Collapse>
</Navbar>
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: check my answer below. You need to put as={Link}

Answer (score 1):

i had the same problem, i solve it by removing the source of the problem or comment it!

```js
as={{
      $$typeof: Symbol(react.forward_ref),
      render: LinkWithRef
    }}
    to="/navbars"
```

Answer (score 1):

The "as" property should indicate which class you want to use, example:

```
<Navbar.Brand as={Link} href="/">
```

where link comes from
import Link from "next/link";

It seems to be an isue on the translation or creation of the docs, so you should replace:

```
<Navbar.Brand
as={{
  $$typeof: Symbol(react.forward_ref),
  render: LinkWithRef
}}
to="/navbars"
```

> 

for

```
<Navbar.Brand as={Link} href="/">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to uncomment the React import statement. For example: `import React from 'react'`

Answer (score 0):

```
i have the same problem.My flowbite-react navbar does not seem to work

import  React from 'react'
import { Navbar } from 'flowbite-react'


function Header() {
  return (
      <Navbar
  fluid={true}
  rounded={true}
>
  <Navbar.Brand
    as={{
      $$typeof: Symbol(react.forward_ref),
      render: LinkWithRef
    }}
    to="/navbars"
  >
    <img
      src="https://flowbite.com/docs/images/logo.svg"
      className="mr-3 h-6 sm:h-9"
      alt="Flowbite Logo"
    />
    <span className="self-center whitespace-nowrap text-xl font-semibold dark:text-white">
      Flowbite
    </span>
  </Navbar.Brand>
  <Navbar.Toggle />
  <Navbar.Collapse>
    <Navbar.Link
      href="/navbars"
      active={true}
    >
      Home
    </Navbar.Link>
    <Navbar.Link
      as={{
        $$typeof: Symbol(react.forward_ref),
        render: LinkWithRef
      }}
      to="/navbars"
    >
      About
    </Navbar.Link>
    <Navbar.Link href="/navbars">
      Services
    </Navbar.Link>
    <Navbar.Link href="/navbars">
      Pricing
    </Navbar.Link>
    <Navbar.Link href="/navbars">
      Contact
    </Navbar.Link>
  </Navbar.Collapse>
</Navbar>

  )
}

export default Header
```

Comment: check this resource https://flowbite-react.com/storybook/?path=/docs/components-navbar--default-navbar , try removing the "as" and "to" attributes in the Navbar.Brand Component and use the href="your/home/page"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The link in the comment by christianbueno.1 is broken. They probably suggest to ditch the fancy stuff from the `Navbar.Brand` opening tag. It should work like this: `<Navbar.Brand href="https://flowbite-react.com">`.

Comment: check my answer below. You need to put as={Link}

Answer (score -1):

It is now fixed, check the website docs again:

https://www.flowbite-react.com/docs/components/navbar